# PHP - Remove item from array by given key paths (in another array)

Tags: php, arrays

Here I have a problem to be solved.
There will be two arrays:

```
<?php
$main_array = array(
  'item-1' => array(
    'item-1-1' => array(
      'item-1-1-1' => 'value',
      'item-1-1-2' => 'value',
    ),
    'item-1-2' => 'value'
  ),
  'item-2' => 'value',
  'item-3' => array(
    'item-3-1' => array(
      'item-3-1-1' => 'value',
      'item-3-1-2' => 'value',
    ),
    'item-3-2' => 'value',
  ),
);

$key_paths_to_deleted = array(
  array('item-1', 'item-1-1', 'item-1-1-1'),
  array('item-2'),
  array('item-3', 'item-3-1'),
);
```

I need to remove items from `$main_array` based index path given in `$key_paths_to_deleted`. So resulting `$main_array` should be as given below.

```
$main_array = array(
  'item-1' => array(
    'item-1-1' => array(
      'item-1-1-2' => 'value',
    ),
    'item-1-2' => 'value'
  ),
  'item-3' => array(
    'item-3-2' => 'value',
  ),
);
```

That means I will have 'path's to the items in main array to be removed.

Key and values in main array can be any possible values in PHP, no structured naming for keys, and values may be duplicate.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: what you tried ? Did you tried at all ?

Comment: Yes, I had tried and keep trying...

Answer (score 0):

Function `remove()` is recursive and will check key in parameter. If key is found, it will delete it.

Parameter `$last` indicate if it's last key.
In your example, it will delete all content of `item-3-1` but not delete `item-3`

```
function remove(&$array, $remove, $last = false)
{
  foreach($array as $key => &$value) {
    if(is_array($value)) remove($value, $remove, $last);

    if(is_array($value) && $key == $remove && $last == true) unset($array[$key]);
    if( !is_array($value) && $key == $remove) unset($array[$key]);
  }
}
```

---

```
for ( $i = 0 ; $i < count($key_paths_to_deleted) ; $i++ )
{
  $last = count($key_paths_to_deleted[$i]) - 1;

  for ( $j = $last; $j >= 0 ; $j-- )
    remove($main_array, $key_paths_to_deleted[$i][$j], ( $j == $last ) ? true : false);
}
```

Result :

```
Array
(
    [item-1] => Array
        (
            [item-1-1] => Array
                (
                    [item-1-1-2] => value
                )

            [item-1-2] => value
        )
    [item-3] => Array
        (
            [item-3-2] => value
        )
)
```